# Error during PolyBase installation in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, polybase

I'm trying to install Polybase in SQL Server 2019, but I keep getting following error:

> Error installing SQL PolyBase
>   User, group, or role 'NT Authority\NETWORK SERVICE' already exists in the current database. Changed database context to 'DWDiagnostics'.
>   Error code: 0x84BB0001

I'm doing everything just like in documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-installation?view=sql-server-ver15). What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you installing using the UI installer, or are you installing via command line? Is this a new SQL Server instance install, or are you adding the PolyBase features to an existing installation?

Comment: I'm using UI installer and I was trying both ways: installing a new instance and adding new feature. In both cases I got the same error. What is more my friend got the same error on his PC.

Comment: Hi, just had a chat with some Microsoft people. Can you please email polybase@micrsoft.com and attach the install log files from: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\yymmdd_ts\sql_polybase_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log.

Comment: Ok I will. Thank you.

Comment: Mariusz, did you come right with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install using any system account, you need either a domain account or a new user with Administrator role.